# How would I target an element that is visible but beneath another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a circular graphic that is mainly based on pure HTML and CSS. A little JavaScript and JQuery is added for curving text and interaction that is planned for later on.

The problem I have is, that when I click on the upper right element, it is covered in party by the upper left element. So when I check which element is clicked through an alert, I see that for 50% of the upper right element's area, the number of the upper left element is returned.

[image: screenshot of the circular graphic I built with highlight of the problem area]

How would I target precisely the elements that I click on? This is needed for linking to different pages of our web project later on.

I created a JSFiddle to show the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/niklasbuschner/gj67md4u/4/

The code looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function textRotation() {
    new CircleType(document.getElementById('demo1')).radius(185);
    new CircleType(document.getElementById('demo2')).radius(185);
    new CircleType(document.getElementById('demo3')).radius(185);
  }
  textRotation();
  $('#demo1').children('div').addClass('pie__segment__path-text__rotation1');
  $('#demo3').children('div').addClass('pie__segment__path-text__rotation3');
  $('.pie__segment').on('click', function() {
    var link_target = $(this).data('href');
    alert('KLICK' + link_target);
  });
})
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.pie {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: calc(var(--size, 400) * 1px);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(var(--size, 400) * 1px);
}

.pie__segment {
  --a: calc(var(--over50, 0) * -100%);
  --b: calc((1 + var(--over50, 0)) * 100%);
  --degrees: calc((var(--offset, 0) / 100) * 360);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(var(--a) var(--a), var(--b) var(--a), var(--b) var(--b), var(--a) var(--b));
  clip-path: polygon(var(--a) var(--a), var(--b) var(--a), var(--b) var(--b), var(--a) var(--b));
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(90deg) rotate(calc(var(--degrees) * 1deg));
  transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(90deg) rotate(calc(var(--degrees) * 1deg));
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: calc(1 + var(--over50));
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pie__segment:after,
.pie__segment:before {
  background: var(--bg, #e74c3c);
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.pie__segment:before {
  --degrees: calc((var(--value, 45) / 100) * 360);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%) rotate(calc(var(--degrees) * 1deg));
  transform: translate(0, 100%) rotate(calc(var(--degrees) * 1deg));
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}

.pie__segment:after {
  opacity: var(--over50, 0);
}

.pie__segment .path-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: -82px;
  bottom: 122px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.pie__segment .path-text span div {
  height: 2.5em !important;
}

.pie__segment .path-text span div span:last-child {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.pie__segment .path-text.demo1 {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.pie__segment__path-text__rotation1 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.pie__segment .path-text.demo2 {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.pie__segment .path-text.demo3 {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.pie__segment__path-text__rotation3 {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.pie-body {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: #73c6be;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pie-body p {
  line-height: 260px;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #0896A5;
}
```

```html
<div class="pie-container" style="position: relative; top: 100px; left: 100px;">
  <div class="pie">
    <div class="pie__segment" data-href="1" style="--offset: 0; --value: 33.33333; --bg: #089baa">
      <div class="path-text demo1">
        <span id="demo1">BEISPIEL EINTRAG +</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie__segment" data-href="2" style="--offset: 33.33333; --value: 33.33333; --bg: #066f7a;">
      <div class="path-text demo2">
        <span id="demo2">NÄCHSTER EINTRAG +</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie__segment" data-href="3" style="--offset: 66.66666; --value: 33.33333; --bg: #044249;">
      <div class="path-text demo3">
        <span id="demo3">WEITERER EINTRAG +</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pie-body">
    <p>Kernaussage</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would (when KLICK3 is detected) cancel the actual click, detect the mouse position relative to the horizontal center of the element, and then trigger the appropriate click based on that.

Comment: Unable to replicate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/2L5jv6nf/

Comment: @Twisty I see the issue in your fiddle too

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava it's not clear what the issue then. I am seeing the console entry with the proper details for each click.

Comment: @Twisty Are you clicking in the small portion marked in red by OP? It does show `KLICK3` instead of `KLICK1`

Comment: I'm reproducing the problem in the fiddle with Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88

Comment: @Niklas You should consider doing this using SVG, which will not present the `z-index` issues

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I was not, I see it now: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/2L5jv6nf/3/ I agree with using SVG since the BOX model is spilling over. Can try to fix with `z-index` otherwise.

Comment: `clip-path` works nicely, but (of course) it bombs in IE, too bad. https://jsfiddle.net/vkt7wa1j/

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I already thought about using SVG but I am not very familiar with it. Would you be able to assist through an Upwork job? Otherwise I am a little bit lost. Thanks to everyone for your helpful comments!

Comment: @NiklasBuschner Added an answer, see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use `svg`

```js
function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
  var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees - 90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

  return {
    x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
    y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
  };
}

function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {

  var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
  var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

  var largeArcFlag = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";
  var sweepFlag = endAngle > startAngle ? 0 : 1; //sic

  var d = [
    "M", start.x, start.y,
    "A", radius, radius, 0, largeArcFlag, sweepFlag, end.x, end.y
  ].join(" ");

  return d;
}

window.onload = function() {
  let arc1 = document.getElementById("arc1")
  let arc2 = document.getElementById("arc2")
  let arc3 = document.getElementById("arc3")

  arc1.setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, 120, 0));
  arc2.setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, 240, 120));
  arc3.setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, 360, 240));

  let text1 = document.getElementById("text1")
  let text2 = document.getElementById("text2")
  let text3 = document.getElementById("text3")

  let textPath1 = document.getElementById("textPath1")
  textPath1.setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 95, 120, 0));

  let textPath2 = document.getElementById("textPath2")
  textPath2.setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 95, 240, 120));

  let textPath3 = document.getElementById("textPath3")
  textPath3.setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 95, 360, 240));


  [arc1, arc2, arc3, text1, text2, text3].forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", e => {
      console.log(e.target.getAttribute("link"))
    })
  })
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(36, 41, 46);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

svg {
  /*outline: 2px solid lightgreen;*/
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  transform: scale(1);
}

path,
text {
  cursor: pointer;
}

text {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
   <circle shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" cx="200" cy="200" r="100" fill="#73c6be" stroke="none" />
  <path shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" id="arc1" fill="none" stroke="#089baa" stroke-width="30" link="Link1.html" />
  <path shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" id="arc2" fill="none" stroke="#066f7a" stroke-width="30" link="Link2.html" />
  <path shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" id="arc3" fill="none" stroke="#044249" stroke-width="30" link="Link3.html" />

  <path id="textPath1" fill="none" stroke="none" />
  <path id="textPath2" fill="none" stroke="none" />
  <path id="textPath3" fill="none" stroke="none" />

   <text id="text1">
     <textPath 
      href="#textPath1"
       link="Link1.html"       
      startOffset="15%"
      >BEISPIEL EINTRAG+</textPath>
   </text>
    <text id="text2">
     <textPath 
      href="#textPath2"    
       link="Link2.html"
      startOffset="10%"
      >NACHSTER EINTRAG+</textPath>
  </text>
    <text id="text3">
     <textPath 
      href="#textPath3"
      link="Link3.html"
      startOffset="10%"
      >WEITERER EINTRAG+</textPath>
  </text>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is brilliant. Would love to fully develop the element with your help, paid of course. If you are interested, I would be happy to have you on board.

Comment: The thing is, I'm a little swamped with work atm and just created a small snippet to point you in the right direction. You can email me at `anurag.131092@gmail.com`, though it might be a while till I get free to work